# ListView Background Color using logics

Tags: android, listview

I had revise through the google and stackoverflow..

[Android - ListView with 2 different Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305176/android-listview-with-2-different-colors)
i found this post useful for changing background color.. but how if i would like to changed the background color according to logics?

for Example my code already set up a convertView. like below

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

        if(convertView==null) 
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rest_list, null); 

        TextView id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.id); // title 
        TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name); // artist name 
        TextView area = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.area); // duration 
        TextView type = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.type); // duration 
        ImageView image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image); // thumb image 

        HashMap<String, String> restaurant = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        restaurant = data.get(position); 

        // Setting all values in listview 
        if(name != null){
        id.setText(restaurant.get(RestaurantList.TAG_ID)); 
        name.setText(restaurant.get(RestaurantList.TAG_NAME)); 
        area.setText(restaurant.get(RestaurantList.TAG_AREA));
        type.setText(restaurant.get(RestaurantList.TAG_TYPE));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(restaurant.get(RestaurantList.TAG_IMAGE), image); 
        }

    //this line is example.. 
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.GREEN);

    // i wanna do like this (if there is name MacDonal in NewYork , set the background to green. otherwise leave it white.

     // it gives me red underline at the 'logic operation' sentence. 
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(name == MacDonal && area == newYork ? Color.WHITE : Color.GREEN);
        return convertView; 
    }
```

anyone knows how to fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor((restaurant.get(RestaurantList.TAG_NAME).equals("MacDonal") && restaurant.get(RestaurantList.TAG_AREA).equals("newYork")) ? Color.GREEN : Color.WHITE);
```

I don't know it you understand the ternary operator used here. Tell me if you need explanation

Comment: perfect. this code works! Thanks a lot Naveen! I'll digest it. =D

Answer (score 1):

use something like category. For ex: If you some category as one color and another category as one color then define `int category1 = 1` and `category2 = 2`. and overide getview method. then you adapter might be

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v = convertView;
if (v == null) {
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
}
TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
if (category1 == 1)
    text.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
if (category2 == 2)
    text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
return super.getView(position, v, parent);
}
```

I hope this will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you , in your adapter setTextcolor,Backgroundcolor as per require

```
 public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(view == null)
        {           
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfriends_item, null); 
            holder =  new ViewHolder();
            holder.performerImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.mfitem_iv);
            holder.performerStar = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.star);
            holder.performerName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mfitem_tv_name);

            holder.performerAge = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mfitem_tv_age);
            holder.performerPoints = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mfitem_tv_pts);

            holder.performStatus = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mfitem_tv_status);

            holder.performLookingfor = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mfitem_tv_lookingfor);
            holder.txtid = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtid);     
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }       


           //here you can set color as per require
            try
            {                                                                                           

                if(topPerformersSetGet.getPerformerDataSetGets().get(position).getOnline() == 1)
                {
                    holder.performStatus.setText(HotSpotSettings.ONLINE);   
                    holder.performStatus.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                }
                else
                {
                    holder.performStatus.setText(HotSpotSettings.OFFLINE);
                    holder.performStatus.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.clrred));

                }           


            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }                       

            return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView performerImage;
        ImageView performerStar;
        ImageView perforonlinestatus;       
        TextView performerName;
        TextView performStatus;     
        TextView performerAge;
        TextView performLookingfor;
        TextView performerPoints;
        TextView txtid; 
    }
```