# List view customization in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I am making an android app. I want to make List-view as above image. In this Listview I am fetching Items value from database using JSON webservice and how can change List-view Items border color and background image.  Items 1,3,5,7,9 = same color and same background and List-view Items 2,4,6,8,10 = same color and same background. How can i do. please help me.

[image]

Comment: might be similar to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305176/android-listview-with-2-different-colors)

Comment: can you put your getView() method so that I could edit it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this tutorial can help you: [android.amberfog.com](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296)

Just 2 types of items: in getView you doing almost the same, that in  tutorial, but, instead of separator you setting your list item. 
HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to write an xml file with a dashed stroke. ask me if you need to know how to do it.

1. Use two separate background xml files: background_yellow_stroke.xml and background_back_stroke.xml put them in a new res folder and name it: colors
2. In your adapter's getView() method: use mod (%) operand to determine whether your position is even or odd.

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private List data;
    private Activity context;

```
public NoteArrayAdapter(Activity context, int resID,
        List<Note> data) {
    super(context, resID);
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return data.size() == 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convetView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);
    }

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.colors.background_yellow_stroke.xml )
       } 
    else
       {
           convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.colors.background_black_stroke.xml )
       }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Done.

Comment: how can i put scissor in top right plach on dashed stroke.

Comment: @Amardeep: That's a complete question, but I'll answer it here:

 use two layouts, put the stroke to the inner layout and use layout_margin for it, put the sissor to the upper-right corner of the outer layout (use relative layout) and you are good to go :)